# How to get java file path deployed on web server?

Tags: java, server

I have abc.jar deployed on web server http://localhost:8080/test/scripts folder.

In that abc.jar file I have Path.java class where I have to write the code to get the URL of the server where the abc.jar file is present. The output should be http://localhost:8080/test/.

How to get the path?

Comment: JAR file or WAR file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you wanna get contextPath of your deployed .war file in the servlet class Path.java [I am assuming you are using servlets here],

```
public static String getURLWithContextPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return request.getContextPath(); // this method will provide you desired path.
}
```

for more detail about the contextPath,

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()

Comment: Path.java is not servlet. It is simple java class. How can we get the contextpath from simple java class?